# Can I change background/text colour during a program in python?

Tags: python, text, colors, background

I am looking to either change the colour of background shell or the text during while the program is running. I am aware I can change the themes in the options to do this permanently but that is not what I am looking for. Is it possible to do this or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest colorama library:

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/colorama

Example:

```
from colorama import Fore, Back, Style

print(Fore.RED + 'some red text')
print(Back.GREEN + 'and with a green background')
print(Style.DIM + 'and in dim text')
print(Style.RESET_ALL)
print('back to normal now')
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is.  It might not work in all terminals, but there are escape sequences for this:

```
print("\033[34;42mMy text\033[m")
```

will print `My text` in blue on a background of green.

The escape sequence is `\033[` followed by `;`-separated numbers, followed by `m`.  To end the color, you use `\033[m`.  The numbers are `1` to make the text bold, `3` with another number to make the text the color of the other number, and `4` with another number to make the text background the color of the other number.  The other numbers mentioned for `3` and `4` are the following:

```
0 -> Black
1 -> Red
2 -> Green
3 -> Yellow
4 -> Blue
5 -> Purple
6 -> Cyan
7 -> Light Gray
```

Answer (score 1):

It is possible even if it is not that straight forward. Fortunately, there is a nice library called `colorama` that can help you out with this.
Check it out here http://pypi.python.org/pypi/colorama

Without using extra libraries, you have to use ANSI escape chars, http://ozzmaker.com/add-colour-to-text-in-python/

Comment: i tried all these methods and I can not get them to work. when trying colorama it says there is no module called colorama and when using the ANSI characters it just prints the characters as a string

Comment: you have to 'pip install colorama' first!

Comment: and if you are using python2 you need to import print_function, `from __future__ import print_funtion` or remove the print parenthesis.